# Algorithm for online approximation of a slowly-changing, real valued function

Tags: language-agnostic, function, machine-learning, neural-network, approximation

I'm tackling an interesting machine learning problem and would love to hear if anyone knows a good algorithm to deal with the following:

- The algorithm must learn to approximate a function of **N inputs** and **M outputs**
- N is quite large, e.g. **1,000-10,000**
- M is quite small, e.g. **5-10**
- All inputs and outputs are **floating point values**, could be positive or negative, likely to be relatively small in absolute value but no absolute guarantees on bounds
- Each time period I get N inputs and need to predict the M outputs, at the end of the time period the actual values for the M outputs are provided (i.e. this is a **supervised learning** situation where learning needs to take place **online**)
- The underlying function is **non-linear**, but not too nasty (e.g. I expect it will be smooth and continuous over most of the input space)
- There will be a **small amount of noise** in the function, but signal/noise is likely to be good - I expect the N inputs will expain 95%+ of the output values
- The underlying function is **slowly changing over time** - unlikely to change drastically in a single time period but is likely to shift slightly over the 1000s of time periods range
- There is **no hidden state to worry about** (other than the changing function), i.e. all the information required is in the N inputs

I'm currently thinking some kind of back-propagation neural network with lots of hidden nodes might work - but is that really the best approach for this situation and will it handle the changing function?

Comment: If the function changes slowly (and therefore approx. continuously) over time, then isn't it really a function of N+1 inputs, with the same criteria applying to the time as apply to any of the other N inputs?

Comment: @Steve - very interesting point! If that way of thinking helps get a better solution then I'm all for it. The main issue I see is that I'm not sure how you then do "online" learning - would the algorithm need to revisit a large portion of history to incorporate each new sample?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know anything about machine learning. So beyond that little insight I don't think I can contribute anything useful. Suppose that in the real data your program sees, input number 435 of 1000 just so happens to be monotonic increasing over time. If your program can't treat time as just another input, I don't see how it will handle that real data either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your number of inputs and outputs, I'd also go for a neural network, it should do a good approximation. The slight change is good for a back-propagation technique, it should not have to 'de-learn' stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I think stochastic gradient descent (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) would be a straight forward first step, it will probably work nicely given the operating conditions you have.

Answer (score 1):

I'd also go for an [ANN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). Single layer might do fine since your input space is large. You might wanna give it a shot before adding a lot of hidden layers.

@mikera What is it going to be used for? Is it an assignment in a [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) course?

Comment: Thanks for the hints - it's not an assignment, actually it's for a personal robotics simulation project, which has meant me having to delve quite deeply into some machine learning theory :-). The data is (roughly) a time series of internal state and sensor data. The outputs are basically a prediction of certain aspects of the future state.